# Find registry value types in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, types, registry, dword

I am creating a very basic registry viewer in VB.Net.
I need to find the type of registry key (String, DWORD, Binary .etc) but I dont know how to using VB.Net and I cannot find an answer anywhere.
http://s22.postimg.org/98acwiz01/Capture.png
Here is a picture of what I am trying to do.
On line 7, I am trying to get the type of registry value it is.
You can see I've tried and failed miserably.
Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetValueKind()` method of the `RegistryKey` class to retrieve the data type of the value. `RegistryKey` is part of the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace. For example:

```
    Dim subKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion")
    Dim type As RegistryValueKind = subkey.GetValueKind("ProgramFilesDir")
```

The `Registry` class has a number of static fields which give access to the base keys. For example, `Registry.CurrentConfig` gives access to the keys under HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG. There are seven of these different starting points so to get the type of any specified key you will need to check the start of the key name and use the appropriate starting point. You can then specify the rest of the key in the `OpenSubKey()` call remembering to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the "CurrentUser" part?
I want to be able to do this with ANY type of value in any key for example: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: This thing always gives an IOException error and I have no idea why.

Comment: Is it saying that the key does not exist? I am just digging out some code I wrote a while back that makes the class a but easier to use.

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example of this code? Without the "CommonID" part?

Comment: Have updated answer with a better piece of example code.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Works great.
It returns a number each time, what do each mean?

So far I've worked out:
1 = String
3 = Binary
4 = Dword
11 = Qword
7 = Multistring
2 = Expandable string

Comment: The full list is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: minus 1 = None; 0 = Unknown; 1 = String; 2 = ExpandString; 3 = Binary; 4 = DWord; 7 = MultiString; 11 = QWord

Comment: Thank you very much sir :)
You've really helped me out a lot! :)

Comment: Because I am new and don't have enough reupation to chat, I would like to ask another question.
Is it possible to find the parent subkey in a registry key? Example get "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software" from "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\7-Zip"

Comment: `Dim parentKey As String = key.Substring(0, key.LastIndexOf("\"))` should get you the parent subkey.

Comment: With my example, it does not change "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software" at all. It changes "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\" to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software" but does not give the parent key

Comment: Strange it works ok for me. If I set key = `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` then `key.Substring(0, key.LastIndexOf("\"))` gives me `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. The code is just finding the last occurrence of the \ character and then taking the string from the start up to that point. You could trim any \ characters from the end of the string to make sure that doesn't confuse it.

Comment: Ahaha no sorry, Im just a moron. I made a mistake in my code. It works perfectly, I just understood what I did wrong. Thanks for been an amazing help.

Do you have Skype just in case I ever need to contact you quicker?

Comment: Not a Skype user. I am on SO most days though so will keep my eyes open!